# Excel Search by Date Range and Name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula

```
=INDEX(C1:C8,LARGE(IF((A1:A8>=H2)*(A1:A8<=H3)*(B1:B8=H4),ROW(C1:C8),""),1))
```

it will get the last section from range and name

[image]

but it gets laggy when i created a summary of section where i use this code

[image]

can anyone suggest a formula where it wont get lag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve the result you want, but a lot depends on your version of Excel.

The LARGE and ROW might be causing the delay. You could replace LARGE with MAX.

```
=INDEX(C1:C8,MAX((A1:A8>=H2)*(A1:A8<=H3)*(B1:B8=H4)*ROW(C1:C8)))
```

If you have **Excel 365**, XMATCH might do better. It has an option to search bottom to top:

```
=INDEX(C1:C8,XMATCH(H4,IF((A1:A8>=H2)*(A1:A8<=H3),B1:B8),0,-1))
```

Filtering the lookup array with the IF will reduce the compare operations for XMATCH.

Answer (score 1):

Try either of the following code (using excel vba as a "sub" or within the worksheet as a "function"):

Function Code:

```
Function Test02(name01 As String, MaxDate As Range, MinDate As Range, Rng01 As Range)

'Rng01 Column 1 = "Date"
'Rng01 Column 2 = "jonjon"
'Rng01 Column 3 = "mtce"

Dim Arr01 As Variant ' Array of data
Dim i01 As Long 'Counter
Dim Temp01 As String 'saves the current "mtce" until a larger date is found
Dim TempDate

TempDate = 0
Arr01 = Rng01

For i01 = 1 To UBound(Arr01, 1)
    If Arr01(i01, 1) < MaxDate And Arr01(i01, 1) > MinDate And Arr01(i01, 2) = name01 And TempDate < Arr01(i01, 1) Then
        Test02 = Arr01(i01, 3)
        TempDate = Arr01(i01, 1)
    End If
Next i01
End Sub
```

Instead of having a function, you could use a "Sub" instead and only run it when there is an update, and keep the outputs as static strings.) You might have to edit the following code to repeat over the whole data set, but this should be a good start. If you could give me a better snapshot of how the data is laid out, I might be able to write this code this for you (if this is what you want).

This would be the basis of the sub:

```
Sub Test01()

Dim Arr01 As Variant ' Array of data
Dim i01 As Long 'Counter
Dim Temp01 As String 'saves the current "mtce" until a larger date is found
Dim TempDate

'Rng01 Column 1 = "Date"
'Rng01 Column 2 = "jonjon"
'Rng01 Column 3 = "mtce"

MinDate = Range("H2")
MaxDate = Range("H3")
name01 = Range("H4")
Rng01 = Range("A1:C8")

TempDate = 0
Arr01 = Rng01

For i01 = 1 To UBound(Arr01, 1)
    If Arr01(i01, 1) < MaxDate And Arr01(i01, 1) > MinDate And Arr01(i01, 2) = name01 And TempDate < Arr01(i01, 1) Then
        Temp01 = Arr01(i01, 3)
        TempDate = Arr01(i01, 1)
    End If
Next i01

Range("H5") = Temp01
End Sub
```

Comment: but it so lag does vba can do better ?

Comment: The "Function Test02" can be used within your spread just like any other function (eg Now(), Max(A1,...), Text(...,...), etc" type in "=Test02(H4, H3, H2 , $A$1:$C$8)" into a cell and drag the formula across to other cells. This VBA method will likely be faster than other methods.